# Running a class in CMD

Tags: python, cmd

I am very new to python so please try keep answers very simple, as I struggle to understand the answers on similar questions. I have the file Employee.py

```
class Person:
   def __init__(self,name,job):
       self.name = name
       self.job =job

   def getEmployeeDescription(self):
       return self.name + " is a " + self.job
```

This is stored on my desktop. I want to import this into cmd so I can do for example

> p = Person("James","Builder")

> p.name

Python works on cmd, I just dont know exactly what needs to be typed in to allow me to access this class. I tried cd Desktop > python employee.py, but this just runs the file whereas I want to be able to use the class

Comment: Python does not interoperate with the windows shell. You can't do what you're trying to do.

Comment: How would I do this from the actual python interpreter instead?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open a Python REPL by typing `python` into the command line
2. Import the appropriate class that you want to use
3. Use the class as needed

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
$python3
>>> from employee.py import Person
>>> person = Person('name', 'job')
```

Comment: I get 'no module named employee' where should I store my employee.py file?

Comment: @ScottAdamson the easiest is to launch CMD from the same path as your file. In the File Explorer search bar type in `cmd` and it will launch CMD in your location

Comment: @ScottAdamson I amended MendelG's Answer to use the "employee.py" file name